# Configure OAuth header

Tags: java, oauth

I am trying send request with oauth to Jira.
I add to the URL all oauth parameters.
How do I create the oauth_signature (RSA_SHA1) ?
Is there java library to do that ?

Thanks

```
public void configure(com.atlassian.httpclient.api.Request request) {
URI uri = request.getUri();
String uriStr = uri.toString();
String prefix = "?";
if (uri.getQuery() != null) {
    prefix = "&";
}
uriStr += prefix;
uriStr += "oauth_token=<access_token>";
uriStr += "&oauth_consumer_key=<consumer_key>";
uriStr += "&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1";
uriStr += "&oauth_timestamp=" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
uriStr += "oauth_nonce=" + RandomStringUtils.randomAscii(8);
uriStr += "oauth_signature=" + ???

request.setUri(new URI(uriStr));
```

}

Comment: You might want to put a bit of code in.  People here are good at showing you the mistakes you might be making or directing you if they see what you are trying to do in a code sample.